# Eureka Client Registration under some rules

Tags: netflix-eureka

I have a eureka registry server and other 3 microservices. I am  able to register any of microservices when I set eureka default zone  from eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone property. But I wanted to know if there are other way or some rules which avoids auto register of any microservices to it's registry server?

For the eureka main server I have :

```
# Configure this Discovery Server
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:  # Not a client, don't register with yourself
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
  server:
    enableSelfPreservation: true

server:
  port: 1111   # HTTP (Tomcat) port
```

And in other client(s) i have properties like :

```
# Spring properties
spring.application.name = @nme@

# Discovery Server Access
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone= http://localhost:1111/eureka/

eureka.instance.leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds= 20
#eureka.instance.leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds= 2
```

Here we have clearly stated serviceUrl in properties.

Thanks

Comment: PASTE THE CODE!

Comment: Just edited with properties